# Add figure after paragraph with no text interruption

Tags: floats, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/2975)

Is it possible to add picture figure after paragraph ending (not to interrupt paragraph text).
I have figure that will be wrapped with text and move to the next page if it can't be suited (not enought space) on previous page. But in that case paragraph will be interrupted with figure.

```
\par Some text.. Paragraph ended here.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic.png}
    \captionof{figure}{title}\label{pic:picture}
\end{figure}

\par New paragraph started here. text Some text.....
```

Current state is:
[image: Current state is:]

Want to have next with LaTex:
[image: Want to have next with LaTex:]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please use the search before posting a question. This is the most often asked LaTeX question of all times. See [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/2975) and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/2975).

Comment: Note that `\captionof{figure}` inside a `figure` environment is not required. Just use `\caption`. Also, simply add an empty line before paragraphs. No need to use `\par` explicitly here.

Comment: In this specific case I would simply turn `\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering .. \end{figure}` into `\begin{center} .. \end{center}` and keep the `\captionof{figure}`. Note that `figure`s in LaTeX are *floats* which usually should move at a good position (top or bottom of a page).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't know how to search that:) Now I can completelly finished my bachelor's work with LaTeX:)

Comment: Glad that we can help you. You are very welcome here. There is a search bar on the top right. Also if you start to write a new question there are possible duplicates and related questions displayed on top and on the right.

Comment: Tnank You too a lot for support, without You is wasn't possible to enjoy fully LaTeX and should "play" with editors))